# IE returns wrong z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, z-index

So here is another z-index issue in IE7 I have ran into. I found an explanation of the problem else where but without a fix.

When you have a positioned element with an inline z-index of 0, javascript doesn't return the correct z-index. If a z-index is set to the element in a stylesheet it will return that z-index instead. I get the same result using jQuery too.

Make an html file with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
      $('button').click(function(){
         alert($('#mainBox').css('zIndex'));
      });
   });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
   #mainWr {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      border: 1px solid #333;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
   }
   #mainBox {
      z-index: 1;
      border: 1px solid #555;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50px;
      left: 50px;
   }

</style>

<div id="mainWr">
   <div id="mainBox" style="z-index: 0;"></div>
</div>
<br />
<button type="button">Show #mainBox z-index</button>
```

Open that in IE7. The problem does not exist in IE8.

I jsfiddled it if you have IE7, otherwise you will need to use the code and display it with whatever method you use to emulate IE7:

http://jsfiddle.net/dalelarsen/DndnM/

I am not aware of any solutions. Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved this. The solution is to make sure you grab exactly what is inline yourself and don't rely on the browser.

So I wrote a small object (as a jquery plugin) that parses what is in the element's style attribute and returns the correct value. I am using this for getting the z-index but I wrote it to return any style. You have to pass in the style being requested using the real css name of the style, e.g. 'z-index' instead of 'zIndex'. Maybe at some later day I will rewrite it to account for camel case.

Anyway, here it is:

```
jQuery.fn.inlineStyle = function(stylesName){

   var allStyles = this.attr('style');

   var allStylesArr = allStyles.split(';');
   var allStylesObj = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < allStylesArr.length; i++) {
      var parts = allStylesArr[i].split(':');
      allStylesObj[$.trim(parts[0]).toLowerCase()] = $.trim(parts[1]);
   }
   var rStyleVal = false;
   if (allStylesObj[stylesName]) rStyleVal = allStylesObj[stylesName];
   return rStyleVal;
};
```

Comment: I didn't notice that mistake. Yes, you have to pass in the exact style name just as you would write it in a CSS file. Was there a reason you thought `zIndex` would work?

Comment: @Brad, the above is a new script I wrote. Before I was using jQuery's .css(), which does allow accepting zIndex, because camelCase is what javascript uses. Javascript can't have hyphens in variable and object names. My script doesn't rely on the browser returning the actual current style, it gets only what is in the style attribute on an element. In my script I simply didn't have the time to account for camelCase.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken providing a negative z-index resolves this issue.  A developer here ran into that issue and I believe that was the resolution.

Comment: I believe that if you specify a `z-index` of 0 (or don't specify at all) the browser gets to determine the layering of those items. Letting IE have that discretion is the layout equivalent of letting the bull in your china shop.

Comment: @Brad perhaps, I was speaking from a recent experience though.  Wherein a change to a negative z-index allowed for IE to properly handle our page.

Comment: Thanks of your comments. The question is matter of how IE returns the zIndex value, not how it looks on the page. Its a JS getter question, not a css issue. Changing it to anything other than 0 of course will then return the correct z-index. The problem exists when it is 0. That is when I need it correct.

Comment: @Brad, +1 for stating why this happens.

Comment: @Woot4Moo, I wasn't combating your answer, but explaining it. I actually gave you +1